# Do you fall through the floor when you cast prismatic sphere?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

The spell [*prismatic sphere*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/prismatic-sphere) functions like [*prismatic wall*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/prismatic-wall) which says that the 7th violet layer is an "[e]nergy field destroys all objects and effects. Creatures sent to another plane (Will negates)."

The *prismatic sphere* description says that the *sphere* is complete and not just an above ground hemisphere: "Typically, only the upper hemisphere of the globe exists, since you are at the center of the *sphere*, so the lower half is usually occluded by the floor surface you are standing on."

*Occluded* means that the floor blocks sight. Nothing is said about blocking the effect of the *sphere*. So whenever the spell *prismatic sphere* is cast, does the caster instantly disintegrate anything he's standing on?

Is the *sphere*, instead, actually a hemisphere and a creature can just tunneled past it?

Comment: Also, thematically speaking I always remember thinking of tall castle/wizard's towers that get blocked off by an impenetrable shield of magic. Nothing can approach it from outside, and nothing can approach it from the inside using the stairs either.
But if it doesn't cut through the floor, and the top floor has a hatch-style entrance or something, couldn't people just climb up inside? It kind of ruins the picture.


I guess if the sphere exists just above the floor it would work...

Comment: Maybe the use of the term "occludes" was intended to indicate that you don't have line-of-effect, and therefore can't create that part of the sphere?

Comment: Yes you could tunnel underneath, but if you can cast Prismatic Sphere you can cast Fly, which will give you a full sphere.

Answer (score 4):

No, it won't collapse the floor:

> Typically, only the upper hemisphere of the globe **exists** […]

So actually something does say, pretty clearly, that a floor blocks the effect. RAW and RAI aren't in contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

## A *prismatic sphere* doesn't destroy the surface

The Effect of Color column (as per the table appearing in the description of the spell [*prismatic wall*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/prismatic-wall)) has the layer's *first* sentence's effect occur against attacks, objects, and effects that attempt to pass from beyond the [*prismatic sphere*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/prismatic-sphere) into the *prismatic sphere*. The layer's *second* sentence's effect occurs to any *creature* that attempts to push its way through the *prismatic sphere*.

The seventh violet layer stops any other kind of object or effect not covered by the previous layers that are launched from beyond the *sphere* from entering the *sphere*. Casting *prismatic sphere* while standing on a surface, because of that seventh violet layer, does *not*, for instance, obliterate the surface on which the caster's standing, causing the typical caster to fall 10 ft. so that the caster's at the bottom of the *sphere*.<sup>1</sup>

[The *prismatic wall* table *is* underwritten.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/91874/8610) *Pathfinder* creative director James Jacobs in [this 2010 Paizo messageboard post](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2kkvg?Prismatic-Wall-Violet-Layer-Severe#7) says

> Objects, in this [*prismatic sphere*] case, refers to nonmagical non-living things that are used to try to breach the wall. Like thrown rocks, thrown tables, arrows, catapult boulders, and so on. Any objects or items or whatever that are "attended" (as in, carried or worn by a creature) are NOT destroyed, but travel with the person carrying/holding them off to whatever other plane that person ends up going to. If the person makes their Will save to avoid being sent to another plane, he can stroll right on through the wall with all his stuff intact.
>
> Allowing prismatic wall to automatically destroy every object that passes through it, in other words, IS a bit excessive. The intent of the spell is to prevent anyone from making ranged attacks with weapons or spells or abilities against those on he other side, basically, not to provide a static disintegration wall. The limitations of the table format forced us to be a bit more brief than we should have been in describing it, alas.
>
> Artifacts can't be destroyed by a prismatic wall unless the Destruction line of the artifact says otherwise.

Thus the *prismatic sphere*'s layers have "their effects on creatures trying to attack you [with effects from beyond the *prismatic sphere*] or [on creatures that] pass through the *sphere*[, respectively]." However, this reader had to add all that bracketed information because, as Jacobs says, "The limitations of the table format forced us to be a bit more brief than we should have been in describing it, alas." (Note that Jacobs' *alas* actually dates back *at least* to the 2003 *D&D 3.5e*'s description of the spell [*prismatic wall*](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/spellsPtoR.html#prismatic-wall) from which *Pathfinder* draws many spells.)

To be clear, the first red layer doesn't destroy mundane ranged weapons it catches within its area when the spell's cast nor does the third yellow layer prevent creatures caught within the area when the spell's cast from ever again using their poison or petrification special abilities. (And, instead, those two layers can deal up to 100 points of damage to a creature attempting to penetrate the *sphere*.) Similarly, the seventh violet layer doesn't destroy anything it touches *when the spell's cast* but, instead, destroys objects and effects launched from outside the *sphere* at the *sphere*. (And that layer, instead, can *plane shift* to random plane a creature attempting to penetrate the *sphere*.)

### The spell isn't *prismatic hemisphere*, but it may seem that way

The spell *prismatic sphere* is *still* a spell, and a spell needs [line of effect](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/glossary#TOC-Line-of-Effect), and that line of effect is typically blocked by a surface on which the caster stands. That's why the description of *prismatic sphere* says, "Typically, only the upper hemisphere of the [*prismatic sphere*] globe exists, since you are at the center of the *sphere*, so the lower half is usually occluded by the floor surface you are standing on."

The word *occluded* here is a [synonym](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1AOHY_enUS709US709&q=occlude%20definition&oq=occlude%20definition&gs_l=serp.3..0i7i30k1j0j0i7i30k1l8.2732.2732.0.4124.1.1.0.0.0.0.230.230.2-1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..0.1.229.YOG1_ITiM34) for *stopped*. The *sphere* doesn't typically have line of effect to below the surface on which the caster stands, so usually "only the upper hemisphere of the globe exists" because the game assumes no one's casting *prismatic sphere* while flying.<sup>2</sup> That is, if the caster's standing on a surface when the spell's cast, the spell's *entire* area—a 10-ft.-radius sphere centered on the caster—doesn't have line of effect past the surface. Instead, only the unobstructed area is filled with the *prismatic sphere*, and that means, despite the spell's name, the usual effect everyone sees is, in fact, a *prismatic hemisphere*.

So a *prismatic sphere* created in an endlessly long 5-ft.-wide-and-10-ft.-tall corridor, for instance, will appear to be a 5-ft. wide multicolored band starting 10 ft. down the corridor on one side the caster, arcing over the caster near the ceiling, and ending 10 ft. down the corridor on the other side of the caster. However, were the corridor somehow widened by 10 ft. in each direction, a multicolored hemisphere would appear around the caster. Then, were the surface on which the caster stood disintegrated, the multicolored *sphere* would appear around the caster! (And, then, of course, the typical nonflying caster would fall…) This is because, like [*antilife shell*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/antilife-shell) or [*globe of invulnerability*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/globe-of-invulnerability), the *prismatic sphere* spell's effect is *partially* blocked by obstructions, yet the spell otherwise has its normal effect for its duration.

(A spell of the [abjuration](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Abjuration) school (like *prismatic sphere*) doesn't need the same kind of clear space for its effect to occur that, for example, a spell of the [conjuration](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Conjuration) school needs. However, an abjuration spell's effect is [blocked by obstructions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/64724/8610) like any other, and its effect doesn't usually, for example, conform *to* the obstructions. That is, casting *prismatic sphere* while in room that's a 5-ft cube won't have *any* effect until line of effect can be traced to 10 ft. beyond the caster as the spell's *entire area* is occluded by the stupid room's walls!)

By extension this means if a caster creates a *prismatic sphere* while the caster stands on a surface, it's possible some creatures can bypass that *prismatic sphere* by traveling underneath the *sphere*. For example, a burrowing creature can safely reach a foe that's standing on a surface and that's within a *prismatic sphere* because there's never line of effect from the exterior of the *sphere* (that's 10 ft. from the caster) to the creature!<sup>3,4</sup>

Of course, a creature that *does* enter a *sphere* this way is now inside a *prismatic sphere* with a creature capable of creating a *prismatic sphere*, and that's a whole 'nother problem to solve.<sup>5</sup>

---

<sup>**1**</sup> That'd be *so* embarrassing.
<sup>**2**</sup> A level 17+ wizard that can fly? Poppycock!
<sup>**3**</sup> How about instead casting *prismatic sphere* while flying?
<sup>**4**</sup> Burrowing actually solves a shocking number of problems.
<sup>**5**</sup> Burrowing causes this problem.