# Do light and darkness from spells turn around corners?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, area-of-effect

Does light or darkness radiated from objects targeted by spells such as Light, Darkness, Daylight and similar turn around corners (act like spread-like emanation)?
[image: spread-like area for Darkness]

Or do obstacles block such effects, reducing their areas?
[image: emanation like area for Darkness]
(and for Deeper Darkness:)
[image: same for Deeper Darkness]

Maybe they behave somewhat entirely different?
[image: Darkness fills a radius]

Comment: Questions about how normal torches work and questions about how magic spells work are different questions. I’ve removed the second question. You can ask about how the light from a torch works by posting a separate question about it.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I'll think about asking second question in a few days.

Comment: Your may also find useful [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/64724/8610). (And kudos on the diagrams. I mean, seriously, Wizards of the Coast should've published a whole damn book of overlays so players would know how to do this!)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## No, they don't

The *light* spell specifically states that it projects light like a torch would, and natural light doesn't go around corners except when reflecting.

The spells *daylight* and *darkness* specifically state that a light-proof covering will block their effect so they will not project around corners either.

In real life, light from any source would reflect around a corner to some extent. The amount would depend on the brightness of the light source and how reflective the wall is. You could assume the same rules apply in the game.

Comment: While this answer is definitely helpful I should note that second paragraph is mostly insignificant for the question's sake. It would be true for both cases listed. Both if illumination behaves like an emanation or if it behaves like spread-like "emanation" it will disapear if fully covered. Difference kicks in when it is covered only partially. If I'll have time, I'll try to add explanatory images to the text.

Comment: Edit was made to the question to emphasise area shaping. You may consider editing your answer to refer my comment, but feel free to leave it as is if you think it solves this issue already.